# How to delete recurring calendar events in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-experience, calendar

I am unable to delete recurring calendar events in salesforce. If I create an event by unchecking repeat then I will be able to delete that particular task but If I check the checkbocx 'repeat' then I will not be able to delete that particular calendar event series or any individual calendar event within that series. Does any one has idea about how to delete such calendar events?

Comment: are you receiving an error msg?

Comment: @mPeixoto No error message, I am not even able to see those buttons (Delete and  Delete Series) even after adding them in layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add Delete, Delete Series and Delete All Following buttons to the page layout. This works considering you have logged in as admin and trying to delete.
But if you trying to delete as a standard user there are some more permissions you may need to configure like Edit Events, Modify all data and also Verify role hierarchy of the logged in user etc,

And also, **Event series is a Beta feature** and consider the following limitations,
1. You can’t edit the start date of a series. Instead, delete the series and recreate it with a new start date.
2. You can’t edit a series from past events.
3.You can’t edit the series from events that fall outside of the series pattern.
4.You can’t delete a series from an event that is edited to occur before the original start date of the series.
5. Attendees can delete individual events only.